# Check if the response comes from okhttp cache while using ktor

Tags: android, okhttp, ktor, ktor-client

I use the following client

```
private val client: HttpClient by lazy {
    HttpClient(OkHttp) {
        engine {
            config {
                cache(Cache(File(App.context.cacheDir, "ktor"), 10 * 1024 * 1024))
            }
        }

        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(jsonSerializer)
        }

        expectSuccess = true
    }
}

...

val response = client.get("https://stuff.com/data")
```

Is it possible to detect if the `response` came from okhttp cache?

Can I somehow get the okhttp Response object and check if `okhttpResponse.networkResponse() == null` ?

Comment: Do you need to check it only once or log that information on every request?

Comment: I want to check it for every request. If the response was from cache, I'd display the data immediately and fetch it again with no-cache (refresh it from the network)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to get a reference to an instance of the `okhttp3.Response`.

Comment: Is it possible to add a cache-hit only interceptor to okhttp and inject a marker header in the response, so that I can check that header from ktor?

Comment: You can add OkHttp's interceptor inside the `engine` block. See https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#okhttp.